# All my photos taken on canon powershot sd300 are overexposed

Tags: digital, camera

I got this camera recently and it’s been working fine in dark setting with flash but whenever i turn off flash or go anywhere with any sort of natural light the pictures come out almost white. I’ve tried auto mode, manual mode and turning exposure and iso all the way down and nothing works. I’ve also tried factory resetting it and it looks the same as before. Here’s an example of manual with the exposure and iso all the way down [image: photo with manual settings] Also, there seems to be a corner in the bottom right of all the photos that isn’t overexposed. I’m wondering if this is just a broken camera issue or what.

Comment: the light sensor is dirty. the flash has it's own ttl sensor and a table of exposure values, so it's unaffected and your exposure is done by controlling the flash output. You should still be able to use manual mode if you ignore the suggested exposure triangle indicator.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a hardware issue to me.  You may want to bring it in for repair.

Before that tho i'd try and cover the viewfinder with your thumb while taking a shot if the problem is better then you have a light leak in your viewfinder.

I'd also be curious to see what a "good" shot looks like indoors.  Does it still have those horizontal lines? is there a difference in exposure in the bottom right corner?

Lastly, see if you can update the firmware on the camera.

I can't comment yet so had to post this as an answer.

Comment: "You may want to bring it in for repair" I think you will have _great_ difficulty finding anyone who will even try and repair a 2004-era compact camera.

Comment: yea, I agree, but if there are customers there are generally servicers around somewhere.